# WP7 Horizontal ListBox Items at the end are getting cut off

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, listbox, items

I am getting this frustrating problem where the last couple of items on my listbox are getting cut off.

I have set my listbox to scroll and display horizontally.  My ItemPanelTemplate contains a VirtualizedStackPanel (When I use a normal stackpanel my listbox only displays a finite number of items where as Virtual one shows all but the last two)

I must point out when I change this from horizontal to vertical everything works fine here is my xaml.

Please Help

```xml
<Grid Name="JumpTo" Visibility="Collapsed" Background="#FF0A0909" Opacity="0.95" >
    <TextBlock Text="Jump To"/>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
             Name="lbJumpTo" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top" 
             SelectionChanged="lbJumpTo_SelectionChanged" 
             Height="248" Width="623" 
             Margin="34,77,0,0" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></VirtualizingStackPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>    
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="200" Height="160">

                    <Grid x:Name="gridLoop" Height="90" Width="150" Background="{x:Null}">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[0][0]}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[0][1]}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[0][2]}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"  Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[0][3]}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3"  Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[0][4]}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[0][5]}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[0][6]}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="6" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[0][7]}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="7" Width="20" Height="20"/>

                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[1][0]}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[1][1]}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[1][2]}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[1][3]}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[1][4]}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[1][5]}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="5" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[1][6]}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="6" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[1][7]}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="7" Width="20" Height="20"/>

                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[2][0]}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[2][1]}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[2][2]}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[2][3]}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[2][4]}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="4" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[2][5]}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="5" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[2][6]}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="6" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[2][7]}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="7" Width="20" Height="20"/>

                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[3][0]}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[3][1]}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[3][2]}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[3][3]}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[3][4]}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="4" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[3][5]}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="5" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[3][6]}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="6" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[3][7]}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="7" Width="20" Height="20"/>

                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[4][0]}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[4][1]}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[4][2]}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[4][3]}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[4][4]}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="4" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[4][5]}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="5" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[4][6]}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="6" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[4][7]}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="7" Width="20" Height="20"/>

                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[5][0]}" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[5][1]}" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[5][2]}" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[5][3]}" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="3" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[5][4]}" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="4" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[5][5]}" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="5" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[5][6]}" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="6" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LoopDisplayMatrix[5][7]}" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="7" Width="20" Height="20"/>

                    </Grid>

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="50" Width="100">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LoopName}" Width="150" Height="40"  />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TempoDisplay}" Width="150" Height="40"  />
                    </StackPanel>

                </StackPanel>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Max control dimensions in Win Phone 7 are 2048x2048, could that be an issue?

Comment: Try to set all the content width as Auto

Comment: Remove width of listbox.

Comment: Cheers Senthil Kumar.  I set the width of the Top Stackpanel in the datatemplate to auto which fixed my problem.

<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="Auto" Height="160">

Answer (score 0):

Cheers Senthil Kumar.  I set the width of the Top Stackpanel in the datatemplate to auto which fixed my problem.